# Combining acute accent getting messed up in the editor (Mac Safari)

Tags: bug, unicode

Stress in Russian language is marked with acute accent: а́, е́, ы́.  As there is no pre-composed cyrillic vowels with acute accent in Unicode, [Unicode Character 'COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT' (U+0301)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm) must be used.

However, for some reason, when I insert it in the editor, the text gets messed up. On the screen shot below, the second word is the same as the first, but with the `U+0301` added after `е`.

[image: Combining acute accent in the editor]

This is important because stress is distinctive in Russian (there are words with different meaning, being different only in stress). For beginners, it's hard to pronounce the word right if the stress is not marked.

Without proper acute accents, one has to resort to things like cApital lEtters for stress marking, which is not only non-customary, but plain ugly.

**Update**: I'm using Safari 5.1.7 on Mac OS X 10.7.4. This problem seems to be specific to Stack Exchange software: it reproduces on Stack Overflow, but doesn't reproduce on several other sites I've just tried:

[image: Combining accent working as expected]

Comment: You could write like `компл<b>е</b>ксный`, in the meantime. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I am writing with proper acute accents, actually. Italicizing the stressed vowel is less ugly than using a capital letter, but still.

Comment: Could we make an alphabetical list of all letters that might conceivably have stress marks and put it in a meta question that remains "sticky", so it's always at the top of the queue for ease of reference to use with cut and paste? That's how I create stress marks so far, which I can't do from scratch myself. So far I have а́,е́,ё,и́,ы́.

Comment: Hmm what version of Mac OS and Safari are you using? It seems at first glance to be a mac problem rather than something the Stack Exchange team can address... After all the HTML `textarea` input is completely under control of the browser and OS with not much low level rendering controllable by the web app...

Comment: @hippietrail: Sorry, doesn't seem to be so, see question update.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Is it only when typing these in, typing the normal characters and pasting in the acute accent, or pasting in whole words with the acute accents already in them?

Comment: @hippietrail: Happens when typing the combining accent, pasting a word already containing it, or editing an existing post.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac (10.5.8) works (at least pasting, since I cannot figure out how to type a combined accent) with Firefox 12, Chrome 19 and Safari 5.0.6.